# Dereferencing char iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I am new in c++ and just learned about iterators. I have this code:

```
//lines is a vector<string>
for (auto it = lines.begin(); it != lines.end(); ++it) {
    //I want to access each characters in each element (string) of the vector
    for (auto it2 = *it->begin(); it2 != *it->end(); ++it2) {
        cout << *it2 << endl; //error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'char')
    }
    cout << *it << endl; //ok
}
```

I tested asigning the string to a variable:

```
string word = *it;
for (auto it2 = word.begin(); it2 != word.end(); ++it2) {
    cout << *it2 << endl; //ok
}
```

My question is why the second code works while the first doesn't? It seems to me that *it2 is a string and I can access the chars inside it using an iterator but it turns out I have to assign it to a variable for it to work. I don't understand the compiler error. What's the difference?

Comment: `it->begin()` is the `string`'s iterator. `*it->begin()` dereferences that to give you a `char`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is actually on the line above.

```
for (auto it2 = *it->begin(); it2 != *it->end(); ++it2) {
```

The type of `auto` actually translates to `char` because you're dereferencing your iterator too early. `*it->begin()` actually takes `string.begin()` and dereferences it, returning a `char`. To fix, simply remove the iterator dereference from your `for` statement, like this:

```
for (auto it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2) {
```

Comment: And of course, since he's using `auto`, he has C++11, and can use `for ( std::string line: lines ) { for ( char ch: line ) { ... } }`

Comment: @James Kanze yes I did it before. But the exercise in the book I'm reading is to try it using iterators :)

Comment: @user3263252 Out of curiosity, which book is it?

Comment: @Joseph Mansfield c++ primer fifth edition part of Exercise 3.22. I reread the part about arrow operators to check if there's an error in the book just now, and for some reason completely missed the missing "*" in the "->" example! Tsk!

Answer (score 1):

You mixing dereference `*` together with pointer member `->`, use only one:

```
for (auto it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2) {
```

or

```
for (auto it2 = (*it).begin(); it2 != (*it).end(); ++it2) {
```